# 404 not found on running URL after bluemix deployment

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I have written a sample MVC code using the Spring framework and I have deployed it in Bluemix.

When running the deployed URL, I am receiving the following error.

```
The application or context root for this request has not been found
```

What am i doing wrong ? Anything needed to be changed in web.xml?

> Logs message
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKG0028A: Processing included configuration resource:
>   /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/runtime-vars.xml
>
> [INFO    ] CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 10.005 seconds
>
> [INFO    ] CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
>
> [INFO    ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel httpEndpoint-179 has been started
>   and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 61031.
>
> [INFO    ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been
>   started and is now listening for requests on host localhost  (IPv4:
>   127.0.0.1) port 9080.
>
> [INFO    ] CWSCX0122I: Register management Bean provider:
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.provider.dump.JavaDumpBeanProvider@c68ae63e.
>
> [INFO    ] CWSCX0122I: Register management Bean provider:
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.provider.logging.LibertyLoggingBeanProvider@f0d6d754.
>
> [INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module:
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.liberty.connector.
>
> [INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.liberty.connector has been bound
>   to default_host.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host):
>   http://localhost:9080/IBMMGMTRest/
>
> [INFO    ] CWWKZ0018I: Starting application myapp.
>
> [INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: TaxBillReminder.
>
> [INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module TaxBillReminder has been bound to
>   default_host.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host):
>   http://localhost:9080/
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application myapp started in 2.113 seconds.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features:
>   [json-1.0, jpa-2.0, icap:managementConnector-1.0, beanValidation-1.0,
>   jdbc-4.0, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.0, jsp-2.2, servlet-3.0, jaxrs-1.1,
>   jndi-1.0, appState-1.0, ejbLite-3.1, cdi-1.0].
>
> [INFO    ] CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 9.472 seconds.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a
>   smarter planet.
>
> [INFO    ] SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent
>   storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local
>   application server's memory.
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default 
>   SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created:
>   "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider
>   org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer
>   could not be instantiated
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost startWebApp" at
>   ffdc_15.05.22_06.28.59.0.log TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:28:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.42:31418 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:430a380b-a68e-4123-6ff8-c87348c535a3
>   response_time:0.813611619 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.46:42514 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:c54dff7f-908f-4cc1-49d9-de6d8bd04fe7
>   response_time:0.127545436 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.43:29980 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:23bc66ac-c78e-42ab-5a07-60f99ffc492b
>   response_time:0.117255613 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15". [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.43:23392 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:c255a3fb-5eb1-44f5-4c08-b22222a4c8b7
>   response_time:0.111495485 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15". TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net - [22/05/2015:06:29:04 +0000] "GET
>   / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0" 75.126.70.46:41130
>   x_forwarded_for:"-"
>   vcap_request_id:0c009c84-f0c0-46e9-7b6d-da8e3ff91a55
>   response_time:0.115888617 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context
>   will be used for application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.46:52243 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:c4c29b52-ff3a-48b6-47e4-7e1fce0c3f74
>   response_time:0.187145593 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15". TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net - [22/05/2015:06:29:06 +0000] "GET
>   / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0" 75.126.70.42:11225
>   x_forwarded_for:"-"
>   vcap_request_id:54e0e021-826e-443b-6a7a-5f6bbc28a926
>   response_time:0.132534560 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp.
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15". TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net - [22/05/2015:06:29:08 +0000] "GET
>   / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0" 75.126.70.43:32255
>   x_forwarded_for:"-"
>   vcap_request_id:0ac50be0-e2e9-436c-4e97-d854f78e1f49
>   response_time:0.089186493 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp.
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15". TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net - [22/05/2015:06:29:09 +0000] "GET
>   / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0" 75.126.70.46:39103
>   x_forwarded_for:"-"
>   vcap_request_id:ddc4754a-cf0f-494c-78de-26fcd61ba1af
>   response_time:0.102293236 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp.
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15". TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net - [22/05/2015:06:29:10 +0000] "GET
>   / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0" 75.126.70.42:30749
>   x_forwarded_for:"-"
>   vcap_request_id:fa6ba947-4b8c-474b-4b48-ace26fc3274e
>   response_time:0.091226461 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp.
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15". TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net - [22/05/2015:06:29:11 +0000] "GET
>   / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0" 75.126.70.46:46353
>   x_forwarded_for:"-"
>   vcap_request_id:dfc99308-11c0-4ea7-48ca-b4061b3b4c6f
>   response_time:0.096913693 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp.
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.46:57429 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:4f7e9876-cf5d-46c2-6cb1-19f00329e029
>   response_time:0.100562784 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.43:52701 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:fd13c364-d65a-4ca6-66b1-9bc49c1ea427
>   response_time:0.098537113 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>   [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.42:10951 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:883eb6fc-cdb4-45c6-41f6-cc65970ef256
>   response_time:0.095498510 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.42:30830 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:fc251ebf-da3a-48ae-4312-5218bd83808b
>   response_time:0.134904531 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15". TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net - [22/05/2015:06:29:17 +0000] "GET
>   / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0" 75.126.70.42:54827
>   x_forwarded_for:"-"
>   vcap_request_id:e09e1926-860b-481e-4b48-ed5a66330580
>   response_time:0.084558083 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context
>   will be used for application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.42:31009 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:a9c3a69f-ae27-4c72-7422-608fe01451fd
>   response_time:0.092770319 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.46:55458 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:20ebe389-2371-455a-5832-71c85f48c46d
>   response_time:0.083255059 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.46:44171 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:14081f78-3959-462f-5602-dd474718094c
>   response_time:0.104446356 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0"
>   75.126.70.43:21091 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:930a620b-e6a2-4bdb-6b72-36c072eea29b
>   response_time:0.100104583 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. taxbillreminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:29:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)"
>   75.126.70.43:45588 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:cd805473-5b36-423c-441f-4a013e0c91c3
>   response_time:0.092833842 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211
>
> [INFO    ] SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for
>   application key default_host/
>
> [INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is
>   "15".
>
> [WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for
>   path-->/forms/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[dispatcher:[/forms/*]],
>   application-->myapp. taxbillreminder.mybluemix.net -
>   [22/05/2015:06:30:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
>   75.126.70.43:54400 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:7ca062d7-13ff-4ae2-5441-265d3c2194b5
>   response_time:0.424214609 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211

Comment: Are you able to share your code? On github?

Comment: Also if you could capture the logs produced while pushing the application to Bluemix that would be useful.  See the debugging docs for details on how to access your logs https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/index-gentopic2.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the `context-root` or `contextRoot` that might be defined in your server.xml or web.xml. If there is no `context-root` or `contextRoot` defined then the name of the liberty application is used, see [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_dep_war.html) for the rules. The route to your app running on liberty will normally be something like this:

- http://*your_bluemix_app*.mybluemix.net/***the_liberty_app_name***

The deployed url that you see Bluemix report is the base url for the `application` which in this case is a liberty server, so you need to append your `context-root` (or liberty app name) for your app to it.

You can imagine that you can push 2 or more liberty apps packaged in one liberty server to Bluemix. In this case you have one Bluemix app with 2 web applications running within it that can be accessed like this:

- http://*your_bluemix_app*.mybluemix.net/***the_liberty_app_name_1***
- http://*your_bluemix_app*.mybluemix.net/***the_liberty_app_name_2***

Comment: I tried modifying the URL as mentioned above but it did not work. The same application works locally but after deployment it in Bluemix it did not work as expected.

Comment: Maybe your app on Liberty didn't start? Did you check the logs? `cf logs yourappname --recent`

Comment: 2015-05-21T18:10:07.96+0530 [App/0]      OUT [WARNING ] CWWKZ0126W:  The / conte
xt root value that is specified on the myapp application has no effect.  I could see this warning from logs but i am able to run the same app in the local server

Comment: From the logs can you see that your app on liberty actually starts?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. The solution described at http://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/185697/view.html worked for me.

Looks like the application failed to initialize because of the following:

> [INFO ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer could not be instantiated com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost startWebApp" at ffdc_15.05.22_06.28.59.0.log TaxBillReminder.mybluemix.net - [22/05/2015:06:28:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Java/1.8.0" 75.126.70.42:31418 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:430a380b-a68e-4123-6ff8-c87348c535a3 response_time:0.813611619 app_id:70683a0f-06f4-4ad9-93b7-b37dc8241211

Your application is spring and the autoconfiguration is causing problems.

> With the latest Liberty buildpack, you can set JBP_CONFIG_SPRINGAUTORECONFIGURATION environment variable to '[enabled: false]' to disable Spring auto-reconfiguration. I think in your case the Spring auto-reconfiguration bit is the cause of this problem. Using the cf client execute and then restage your application:
>
> $ cf set-env myApplication JBP_CONFIG_SPRINGAUTORECONFIGURATION '[enabled: false]'